# Multi-level computer assistance calculation levels

Tags: math, logic, organization

Consider a multi-level computer interpreting all levels where all instructions on any level of the computer always get converted to 4 instructions on the level below it. Furthermore, all instructions on a certain level are 3 times as "powerful" as those on the level below it.

If a Level 0 task takes 8.2 ns to execute, how long (in ns) would an equivalent task on Level 3 take to execute? (Give your answer to one decimal place.)

My Work:

```
 level 3:(4 instructions)(2*powerlevel2)
 level 2:(4 instructions)(2*powerlevel1)
 level 1:(4 instructions)(2*powerlevel0)
 level 0:(4 instructions)               =takes 8.2ns for level zero to execute
```

Determine how many ns it takes for level 3 to execute.
   My Reasoning or Question: What does power have to do with the time it takes for a instruction to complete?I suppose that 4 instructions just means that this value is a constant but I know the power given is supposed to be used in a calculation. However, I don't know the relationship with power and time to complete an instruction.If something is twice as powerful then does that mean it is twice as fast?

Please help me reason through this question.
Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered looking at your class notes?

Comment: Of course, I don't understand what he was talking about. first level n*ns, second level n^2 ns, third level n^3 ns

Answer (score 0):

Given,

Time taken at Level 0 = 8.2 ns

It takes 4 instructions of r level are required to interpret a single r+1 level instruction and the machine gets powerful by 3.

So, the computer gets slow down by factor 4/3 at each Level.

Thus, the computer gets slow down at 3rd Level = (4/3)^3

So, time for execution at 5 th Level = 8.2 x (4/3)^3 = 19.4 ns